# how to install and getting start with webrtc

Tags: windows, webrtc

Hi i started to install visual studio 2010 and other prerequiste softwares required for webrtc but i am in confusion on how to get start with this webrtc could anyone tell me to install webrtc in my windows

Comment: Probably like this: http://www.webrtc.org/running-the-demos#TOC-Installing-a-WebRTC-enabled-Chrome-for-Mac-Windows-Linux

Comment: I maintain a [getting started guide for WebRTC](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1GpVqJWxvJ58w6K8Ey-p1BOn6zIABWTj4URiY26d910o/edit#): hope that helps anyone who stumbles upon this question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> prerequiste softwares required for webrtc!!!!

You just need following things for [WebRTC](https://webrtc-experiment.appspot.com/) execution/test/etc. :

1. Web Browser to test
2. Any HTML / JavaScript editor / even you can use Notepad!
3. STURN/TURN server to get Ice Candiates (like: **STUN stun.l.google.com:19302**)
4. Database to save SDP messages
5. Server level technology to pass that saved SDP on the other end to complete the handshake!

and that's all!

Comment: could you tell me where to create our project directory?and how visual studio is use?

Comment: If you want to understand WebRTC....you've to use JavaScript....don't focus on VS in this moment....first control over javascript....understand all WebRTC APIs....create a simple client-side WebRTC working app....if you succeed...then you can go toward VS...or any editor....use any server side langauge: Python, PHP, ASP.NET MVC/WebForms, Java, ---- even Node.js!!!.....

Comment: i tried to implement a basic one http://rhuno.com/flashblog/2012/03/11/tutorial-webrtc-with-html5-and-javascript/ but the stream is not loading.I am not getting where i went wrong!! @Muaz Khan

Comment: Hi, I just did a simple experiment: https://webrtc-experiment.appspot.com/ --- it worked fine for me on same IP Addresses...I've not tested different IP Addresses....You can see the code...it is easy!----each file is separated....offer/answer/etc. ---- To test two peers on a same machine, you must have two webcams with unique microphones....same microphone also causes error!

Comment: no buddy @Muaz Khan i just want to know from where to create our project directory can we run any where our .html file in local system? I've done a basic sample in my local system but it was not streaming even it is not prompting to allow and deny camera in the browser!! could you help me here?

Comment: @Venkat --- you can't test WebRTC on "File Protocol" because "createObjectURL" doesn't work in this case....this function is the backbone of WebRTC because it generates mediaStream Blobs...!!----You can use HTTP/HTTPs.....you can create ASP.NET MVC/WebForms project and put your code in the masterpage file or "Layout.cshtml" file....or Default.aspx/Index.cshmtl files!!!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17731/discussion-between-venkat-and-muaz-khan)

Comment: Personally I used ASP.NET MVC....and I place all my JavaScript/HTML code in the "Index.cshtml" file........I use action methods to store/retrieve SDP blobs / ice candidates.....I use SQL Server...with LINQ to SQL APIs!!.......

Comment: since i want to run a sample file please let me know the way buddy @Muaz Khan